# React native useState doesn't rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was following Mosh's react native course when I ran into this problem after trying to delete item from a flatlist using the useState hook it doesn't rerender is there any thing wrong in this code or this is some sort of bug I have I would really appreciate the help this is my code and I'm using handleDelete as an onPress event:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState(initialMessages);

const handleDelete = (message) => {
    setMessages(messages.filter(m => m.id != message.id));
}
```

Edit: I've used mosh's source code but looks like it still doesn't work so I'll try to reinstall react then try again

Comment: What's the scope of the `handleDelete`? You might have to pass `setMessages` into the function then call it.

Comment: Have you put logs to check if there is a rerender? This should work ideally

Comment: Are you sure that `handleDelete` is invoked?

Comment: @Safder it's inside the function so it's global

Comment: @MaartenDev yeah it is but it doesn't rerender at all

Comment: @TusharShahi sry I'm kinda new so how can I get the logs in the first place?

Comment: Add `console.log(messages)` to your render and check if it changes as required.

Comment: @RohitAggarwal Looks like it's working correctly when pressing on it it removes the selected element but it still doesn't rerender

Comment: how do you know that is does not re-render in first place?

Comment: @RohitAggarwal I've tried again and it looks like I have to double click it in order for it to get removed but still no rerender after its removal

Comment: @SagarDarekar as far as I know if it works correctly the ui will rerender applying the change

Comment: Yes, @Yosseuf that's correct, but it might be possible that this code does not have any issue but reason behind UI is not getting updated is something else. so if you consider adding more code then may be we can help. because this code snippet looks fine.

Comment: What if you try to define a var for the new state like : const newState = messages.filter(m => m.id != message.id). And then call the setMessage function ? Just to check if the behaviour is different

Answer (score 0):

## I've managed to make it work

so Basically I was using react native gesture handler after reinstalling it and expo / react-native I was able to make it work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState(initialMessages);

const handleDelete = (message) => {
    setMessages(messages.filter(m => m.id != message.id));
}

useEffect(()=>{
handleDelete();
},[messages])
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This is not going to help, please make sure at least code is logically correct before adding answer.

Comment: `handleDelete` takes one `parameter` and you have not given any in `useEffect` while calling that function. and even if you do it might go in loop, because you have added `[messages]` as dependency to `useEffect` and handleDelete is changing `messages` causing `useEffect` to trigger again, and this goes on and on.